# Interfaces in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, interface

I have computer on VirtualBox with three interfaces. Two of them are attached to internal network, and one is attached to bridged adapter.
After I launch that computer, I can see all three interfaces.

(enp0s3,enp0s8,enp0s9)

My question is how to recognize which one is the bridged one and which one are the internal ones, so I can set correct IP addresses.
Thanks

Comment: Just set the interfaces to be DHCP, and one of them will pull an IP address in the same range as other machines on your network.  The two NAT adapters will pull IPs from Virtualbox, but it'll be in a different IP range than your normal network.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something similar :-). Thanks

Comment: Since this worked I'll post it as an answer in case others come across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the interfaces to be DHCP, and one of them will pull an IP address in the same range as other machines on your network. The two NAT adapters will pull IPs from Virtualbox, but it'll be in a different IP range than your normal network.